# Unexpected symbol value for uninitialized arrays larger than 64K in COFF object files

Tags: c

**EDIT: I made a mistake when testing with the clang compiler. This works as expected with clang. The unexpected results are produced with Visual Studio 2015. My conclusion is that there is something fishy with Visual Studio 2015.**

I have made an observation I cannot explain regarding the value of object file symbols that represent uninitialized C arrays in COFF object files produced by Visual Studio 2015. That value is supposed to represent the size of the array in bytes, but this is not what I observe. My hope is that someone can explain what is going on here.

Consider the source file testdata_works.c

```
  char testb[0x10002];
```

Consider the source file testdata_fails.c:

```
  char testa[0x10001];
  char testb[0x10002];
```

Now compile:

```
cl -c testdata_works.c
cl -c testdata_fails.c
```

Now run "dumpbin /symbols" on both object files and pay attention to how **the
value of the symbol "testb" differs between the two object files(!)** See below
for the gory details.

```
dumpbin /symbols testdata_works.obj

006 00010002 UNDEF  notype       External     | testb
```

Now for testdata_fails.obj

```
dumpbin /symbols testdata_fails.obj

006 00010001 UNDEF  notype       External     | testa
007 00010041 UNDEF  notype       External     | testb
```

**We note that the symbol testb has the expected value 0x10002 in
testdata_works.obj but has the unexpected value 0x10041 in testdata_fails.obj.**

I have saved the really strange part for last, which may trigger the
proverbial "a-ha" in those who are well versed in the COFF object file
format:

Decrease the size of the arrays in testdata_fails.c to below
0x10000, for example:

```
  char testa[0x0001];
  char testb[0x0002];
```

and compile

```
cl -c testdata_fails.c
```

**The dumpbin command now produces the expected results for symbols testa and
testb:**

```
006 00000001 UNDEF  notype       External     | testa
007 00000002 UNDEF  notype       External     | testb
```

Any suggestions as to what is going on here and how to fix it so it produces the expected results for symbol values larger than 64K?

Final remarks:

I have reproduced this using clang/llvm-nm 7.0.1 instead of Visual
Studio 2015/dumpbin, so it may be related to the COFF format?

You may rightfully ask how I stubled across this. I was studying the BSD
kernel genassym.sh script, and decided to write a small C++ STL program that
achieved the same task from any object file format that can be read by the LLVM libraries. I have this program built, but it does not work properly because the data in the object files is not as expected.

Comment: going above the 1 meg mark overflows the stack area in Windows

Answer (score 0):

COFF doesn't keep the array sizes. A value associated with the array symbol is its starting address. To infer the size of the array `dumpbin` must use some heuristic, e.g. by looking at the neighboring symbols, end of section, etc. Apparently, the heuristic fails. Only the compiler knows why BSS is larger than one would expect.

Comment: I have been playing some more with COFF object files, and from my observations it seems that symbols marked as "Common" should have their symbol value interpreted as the symbol size, not the symbol address. Unless some heuristics are used by llvm-nm/llvm-readobj to derive the size information from address information...

Comment: @stein66 The COFF spec says that the value is an address (or, rather, an offset). A rationale is that the compiler tries to minimize the reloc info, and resolves as much relocations at the compile time as possible. For that it must define the symbol offsets, and the linker doesn't need to know anything else. If this comment is too terse let me know and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: My conclusion is based on my current understanding of the concept of Common linker symbols. The concept of common linker symbols is present in many (all?) object file formats, and probably originated way back with FORTRAN. The same Common symbol may be introduced by several object files. This is usually not allowed because a name is supposed to uniquely reference something in the object file. Not so for uninitialized arrays (they have no content stored in the object file). There is no need to use the symbol value as an address - it is instead used as symbol size so the loader can zero-init.